# What time should be recorded against story points in order to determine velocity and hours per point

Tags: agile

We recently tried to correlate the hours spent on a sprint against the stories assigned to the project (to try and get an idea of velocity and hours per point).  However our recording system only allowed us to put time against a project and so included time such as:

- Customer meetings / phone calls
- Scrums
- Development / testing

Should all of the time for these be taken into account when trying to determine velocity.  Or should only the development / testing time be taken into account that occurred against specific stories.

If everything, what should scrums and meetings be against.  Should there be a separate story for these, or just recorded against a different metric i.e. project-elaboration vs project-development.

If only development do we need a finer grained recording system for recording time spent on a project?

**EDIT**:  As well as velocity we are also trying to get a better idea of hours per point

**EDIT**:  I've had a few comments saying this isn't the way to do it  (that's great).  However no-one in those comments has suggested how we can give a priced quote for the next lot of work if we won't know how long the points took on an hour basis.  The customer wants to know how much cost the next lot of work will be.

Some additional points to note are:
1. The team isn't solely dedicated to this project.  Some time is spent on other work for some people and this may vary.
2. The team may vary in size as the project goes with a member coming and going (I guess this effects estimations, but how?)

Comment: Eh? How many story points did you get done in the sprint? All of these other things are implementation details.

Comment: @Telastyn oh, ok.  So if I wanted to determine hours per point would that make my question different?  I guess that is also what we were trying to achieve.

Comment: why? hours are a terrible metric for work.

Comment: @Telastyn To give out quotes for future work i.e. translate stories to a cost

Comment: @Telastyn hours are the only meaningful metric

Comment: @dreza - points per sprint does that. Your team _completes_ 10 story points per sprint. Your client wants new stuff done. Your staff estimates that to be a 40 point story. How much does it cost to run the team (and support) for 4 sprints?

Comment: @NimChimpsky - poppycock. My hours are not equal to your hours, which are not equal to dreza's hours.

Comment: "We recently tried to correlate the hours spent on a sprint against the stories assigned to the project (to try and get an idea of velocity and hours per point)". NOOOOOOOO!!!!. STOP RIGHT NOW. That never works.

Comment: @Euphoric Ok.  I've got some queries as to why it never works and my specific situation.  Could I chat with you about it in the Whiteboard?

Comment: I don't have time for that, but you should read http://martinfowler.com/bliki/StandardStoryPoints.html . Also the major point of story points, is that they are specific for each team. Being able to convert them to hours will mean that someone will start using same value for each team. Which is obviously wrong.

Comment: @Telastyn I didn't say they were equal.

Comment: @Euphoric  I don't agree that they will be used to compare teams.  I think that's a generalisation.  However thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you have sprints of consistent length (which is highly recommended), then your Velocity is simply the number of story points of the stories that were completed that sprint.

For example, if your team committed to stories for a total of 21 story points and at the end of the sprint you delivered 19 story points worth of completed stories, then your velocity for that sprint is 19 story points.
Note that stories that aren't completed don't count towards your velocity, regardless of how much effort went into them and even if they are 95% done. Only 100% done counts.

If your sprints are not of a consistent length (or if you need to compensate for holidays), then you could work with an average velocity per day. You simply calculate that by dividing the sprint velocity by the length of the sprint (in working days).
If the sprint in the example was 3 weeks (15 days), then you would have an average velocity of 1.19 story point per day.

---

If you use story points also to make a quote and you want to track how much effort goes into a story point, it is best to count only the technical work and add a fixed percentage for overhead (meetings and similar non-technical billable work).
This calculation should be independent from your velocity calculation and can include effort spent on stories that aren't fully done at the end of the sprint.

Comment: Thanks Bart.  We were also looking at trying to determine a more accurate hours per sprint (for pricing etc).  Would that change things?

Comment: @dreza: see my edit